# How to increase frames per second in low poly simple game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with performance in unity. I created a very simple game scene. Very low poly. 2 light sources, 1 Directional 1 Point, I have the Standard Shader with Alberdo and Occlusion texture set (this for all few 3D objects in the scene)

The issue is, I was expecting fps to be around 60 but it is 29ish..

What things I have to consider regarding performance in this scenario? it is very frutstating since it is a very, very simple scene

see images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Profile profile profile. First of all use the Unity profiler to figure out what is actually taking the time. Second of all, don't rely too much on the shown frame rate there. Make an actual build and see what the performance is.

Comment: If it also happens in the device then change your shadow quality, as realtime high quality shadow kills the performance with no mercy. Edit -> Project Settings -> Quality

Answer (score 0):

In your Quality settings, as mentioned by Hamza, set shadow resolution to medium setting and set V sync count to "Dont sync".